# Blind MSSQL Injection - Stacked query in cookies

Tags: sql-injection, cookies, sql-server

I am currently working on a bug bounty program and in one subdomain of my target there is a Blind SQL flaw in a cookie. The back-end is MSSQL/ASP.net however, since cookies are separated by semicolons ";" I can't find a way to try stacked queries.

I know the database instance is running as "sysadmin" user, so stacked queries would allow me to achieve RCE. Is it possible to stack queries in this scenario? If not, is it still possible to achieve RCE (error messages are not displayed)?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1638/  you most likely need to find the appropriate escape character for whatever is reading the cookie.  Unfortunately this sounds like it would be a [Blind SQL Injection][1] which will most likly take a decent amount of trial and error.

  [1]: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Blind_SQL_Injection

Comment: Great point, I didn't think about it. It might be a ASP related function to gather the cookie data, I will look into this thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I may be a bit too late but, in my case, **URL-encoding** the entire payload usually works out all right.

For example, when injecting a on cookie value like *TrackingCookie=ASDFAJKLMNOP*:

```
**ORIGINAL PAYLOAD** => '; SELECT CASE WHEN (1=1) THEN pg_sleep(10) ELSE pg_sleep(0) END -- c
**BECOMES** => %27%3B%20SELECT%20CASE%20WHEN%20%281%3D1%29%20THEN%20pg_sleep%2810%29%20ELSE%20pg_sleep%280%29%20END%20--%20c
```

It may be worth checking out whether the target's server understands URL-encoded payloads beforehand, if possible. It hasn't happened to me, but it may save you from potentially wasting time during any trial-and-error processes attempted while testing with this method.

The payload was taken directly from [PortSwigger's SQL injection cheat sheet](https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection/cheat-sheet) and is meant for PostgreSQL databases.
Hope this will prove helpful to you or anyone else attempting (blind) stacked SQLi.
Stay vigilant and stay ethical!